# Laravel 4.1 _token error on form submit

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-4, csrf-protection

I am doing simple cms in laravel 4.1 , i created many form and they working fine, but the last form which i create throws error on submit.

```
Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException
_token
```

The data posted by form also show on error page.

```
_token  KLlDjuFgaEmuGHKMpFjqSrukYT3sawOYYZLPGxnb
name    asdf
body    asdfasdfa
bio sdfasdf
```

So its mean the _token is also posted  then why i am getting this error.

My form look like this.

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'admin.teachers.store','files'=>true)) }}
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{ Form::label('image', 'Image:') }}
            {{ Form::file('image') }}
        </li>

        <li>
            {{ Form::label('name', 'Name:') }}
            {{ Form::text('name') }}
        </li>

        <li>
            {{ Form::label('body', 'Body:') }}
            {{ Form::textarea('body',null,array('class'=>'ckeditor')) }}
        </li>

         <li>
            {{ Form::label('bio', 'Bio:') }}
            {{ Form::textarea('bio',null,array('class'=>'ckeditor')) }}
        </li>



        <li>
            {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
        </li>
    </ul>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I see one related question to [_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966910/token-error-in-laravel-4-on-update) issue on forum but it didn't help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Post your controllers code, plz... I think I know what is wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In fact your error is `MassAssignmentException`, which means that you are using

```
Model::create($input);
```

In your controller and not using

```
protected $fillable = array('columnA', 'name'...);
```

or

```
protected $guarded = array();
```

In your Model, to tell Laravel which fields of your table are mass assignable.

Take a look at the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: You are right :) and perfect. i fix it after comparing  that specific model with others model. was about to answer my question but  your come first :)